# Coalesce and Nullif

Tags: sql, null, db2

I was wondering why either 1 or 0 turn out (I am a new to SQL).

`SELECT COALESCE(100 / NULLIF(60,0),1)` gives 1.

`SELECT COALESCE(100 / NULLIF(160,0),1)` gives 0.

I know that NULLIF returns NULL when the expressions are equal (but neither ist 0), otherwise it takes the first expression.
COALESCE takes the first non-NULL value.

My question is, why these results come out - I guess I am missing sth here (with brackets?). Can somebody help?

Comment: The first should give you a value of 1.6666667 (100/60) while the second should give you a value of 0.625 (100/160). Appears you are displaying the truncated value of each.

Comment: They don't give you 1 and 0 in Oracle - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ba2435d3eeb1e7e4f765699fc335483f). Are you applying trunc or floor to them, either in the query or in an application; or is you client somehow truncating them for display?

Comment: This doesn't look like an Oracle query, because in Oracle you cannot select without`from`. Please, verify your DBMS

Comment: Good call - they do give 1 and 0 [in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=289e4a5d04b1951a7e10bb0fddbbfeb4) and [PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=289e4a5d04b1951a7e10bb0fddbbfeb4), and [SQLite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=289e4a5d04b1951a7e10bb0fddbbfeb4). So which database are you actually using?

Comment: To @astenx point, I would expect the behavior your are seeing in Teradata, but not Oracle, and that's due to integer math producing integers.

Comment: This is possible in DBMS which treats integer literals as integers and performs integer division (this is reproducible in postgres or SQLite, [for example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5720563c6d77204d4bf67ca4753192d9)). Oracle doesn't have integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to any function in the question.

[Expressions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=elements-expressions):

> **Two integer operands**
>
> **If both operands of an arithmetic operator are integers, the operation
> is performed in binary and the result is a large integer** unless either
> (or both) operand is a big integer, in which case the result is a big
> integer. **Any remainder of division is lost**. The result of an integer
> arithmetic operation (including negation by means of a unary minus
> operator) must be within the range of the result type.

```
100 /  60 == 1
100 / 160 == 0
```